# Problem with closing Unity from native IOS app

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I Have a problem with close unity application in native app. When I'm opening unity app from native application, every time RAM is increasing and after N times application is crashed.

How I run unity app from native:

```
    NSArray* arguments = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];
    NSInteger count = [arguments count];
    char **array = (char **)malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(char*));

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        array[i] = strdup([[arguments objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String]);
    }
    array[count] = NULL;
    char** argv = array;

    [[UnityFramework getInstance] registerFrameworkListener: self];
    [[UnityFramework getInstance] runEmbeddedWithArgc:1 argv:argv appLaunchOpts:@{}];
```

How I close unity app:

```
    [[UnityFramework getInstance] unloadApplication];
-  (void)unityDidUnload:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [[UnityFramework getInstance] unregisterFrameworkListener: self];

    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*) UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate;
    [app.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Here's the repofor more details: https://github.com/DenisDemyanko/UnityProblems

Comment: This seems to be fixed in some of the updates of Unity, since this just stoped happening at some point with no cahnges to code.